# MKV to AVI convertor?

Tags: video, media-converter

Is there a free program that I can use to convert MKV videos to AVI? I tried ffmpeg but it didnt work for me.

Comment: By the way, `ffmpeg` seems to work fine for me. What exactly did you try?

Comment: MKV and AVI are both containers, what formats are you looking to convert to/from? MPEG-4 to H.264? see [this](http://www.movavi.com/formats/AVI.html)

Comment: @thkala I used it on my Windows 8.1 machine using the command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi`, the output video did not work on my Geepas DVD player.

Comment: @indieblue: does your DVD player support the video and audio codec of the resulting file? Many DVD players do not support H.264 video - others do not support plain MPEG-4 either...

Comment: If you cannot find an application that meets your desire, I’d recommend building your own and taking a look at this short tutorial. [https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/multimedia/windows/dotnet/console/convert-video-to-mp4.html](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/multimedia/windows/dotnet/console/convert-video-to-mp4.html)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend three.

*One*: [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/). This tool is a free and open-source multi-threaded transcoding app. It supports nearly any videos including WMV format and has Mac version and Windows version.

Cons:

1. It is too professional to handle for most people;
2. It doesn't support MOV as output format.

*Two*: [iDealshare VideoGo](http://www.idealshare.net/video-converter/convert-mkv-to-avi.html). There is a step by step guide how to use this tool.

Cons:

1. Not free.

*Three*: **Online-Converter**. This kind of converter does a great job on file conversion.

Cons:

1. Like most online converters, the free version of this tool only allows you to convert videos smaller than 100MB. It's too small for video conversion;
2. Your MKV video should be upload to the internet to be converted. This means the risk of pravite information leak is possible.

Comment: I have edited your answer for consistency and added the Handbrake link. Now you please add the link for the 3rd one...

Comment: [iDealshare is a known spammer and GPL violator](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3988).

Answer (score 2):

[Transmageddon](http://www.linuxrising.org/) is another solution.  It is available in the repository for Ubuntu/Mint Linux or Deb versions.  Not batch capable. But, It WILL transcode .mkv to another format (vid & audio) or audio only if you just want an mp3 audio file.  Free works pretty good. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try [this mkv to avi converter](https://freetools.site/video-converters/mkv-to-avi). It is an online service. The file upload limit is 150MB, but you can use it for free and as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MEncoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder), which is often distributed along with [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/):

```
mencoder input.mkv -ovc copy -oac copy -o output.avi
```

That said, there may be one little *issue* with this particular conversion, which may also be the reason you could not use FFmpeg directly. The AVI format does not support all the video and audio codecs that may be included in the Matroska format. For example, you may need to recompress the audio stream to a supported format:

```
mencoder input.mkv -ovc copy -oac mp3lame -o output.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free, open-source and widely used
- Supports most video formats
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), Linux and [Mac](http://ffmpegmac.net/).
- Allows to [convert MKV videos to AVI](https://superuser.com/q/227338/116475)
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, there are many. I will suggest you 2 programs that I use always.

1. [Freemake Video Converter](http://www.filehorse.com/download-freemake-video-converter/) is the first one. I use it most of the time and it will satisfy your needs. Its user interface is user friendly and because of that I don't have to explain the steps of converting.
2. [Format Factory](http://www.filehorse.com/download-format-factory/) is the next one. It too is user friendly and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try [Video Converter](http://www.converter-video.com/). It supports you to [convert MKV to AVI](http://www.converter-video.com/mkv-converter/mkv-to-avi.html) in batch with subtitles. Quite easy to use.